# How to connect a Home computer from another location through Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, wifi, vpn, remote-control

I want to remotely connect my machine in another location. Giving an example, I have PC-1 in California with an IPv4 address: 10.124.XX.XX. I want to connect PC-1 from PC-2 (which is in another location/network) through a Remote Desktop Connection. How can we connect. It is similar to how we access our AWS/Azure servers via Port 443 (such as 10.124.XX.XX:443 through Remote Desktop Connection) but these are physical machines.